# Getting values for clickfunction ,knockout clickbindings

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Pls can someone help me to get the values from click function ,it is not showing anything on console , i need to get the title and location values when clicked on the particular list item

```
 var locations = [
{title: 'Park Ave Penthouse', location: {lat: 40.7713024, lng: -73.9632393}},
{title: 'Chelsea Loft', location: {lat: 40.7444883, lng: -73.9949465}},
{title: 'Union Square Open Floor Plan', location: {lat: 40.7347062, lng: -73.9895759}}


  var viewmodel = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.location = ko.observableArray();
    locations.forEach(function(locat){
      self.location.push(locat)
    })

self.clickEvent= function(currentItem){
    console.log(currentItem.title())


  }
  }

  ko.applyBindings(new viewmodel());
```

html goes like this

```
 <ul data-bind="foreach:location">
    <li data-bind = "text:title,|click:$parent.clickEvent"></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/knockout.js/7101/bindings-form-fields/7835/click#t=201701060946084762053

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Knockout click bindings pass the current model value as the first argument so you shouldn't need to do anything fancy. You have some other errors in your code that might be preventing the event from firing properly.

The "|" symbol in your click binding probably shouldn't be there unless that's a function I'm unfamiliar with:

```
//<li data-bind = "text:title,|click:$parent.clickEvent"></li>
<li data-bind = "text:title, click:$parent.clickEvent"></li>
```

The extra parentheses around your title shouldn't be there either because you've defined title as a string literal not as an observable.

```
//console.log(currentItem.title())
console.log(currentItem.title);
```

You're also missing a number of semicolons and the ending bracket for your locations array.

EDIT: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jlspake/escxx5qa/)

Comment: Thank you so much , it worked , it was indeed the symbol "|" problem